# Large environment scene workflow

Tags: linked-data, scene, optimization, proxies

I'm about to embark on a huge project that requires me to create an environment that is somewhere between 2-5km. The problem I'm facing is that I need most areas/sections of this environment to be pretty detailed, just so I don't blow up my computer. I thought I'd reach out to the community and seek some pointers on how best to approach this.

Is there a way of breaking up the environment into multiple blend files while at the same time calling them into 1 blend file so they are connected? Approaching this as a huge proxied environment.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!